# Unable to connect and clone a project from GitHub using intellij

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin, intellij-14

I am trying to clone a project from github to IntelliJ. 
I have tried the following steps VCS>> CheckOut From Version Controll >>> Git
and tried to clone the project by providing url.

While checking the connection i am getting below error

```
Clone failed: unable to access 'https://git.company.com/Project.git/': could not load PEM client certificate, OpenSSL error error:02001003:system library:fopen:No such process, (no key found, wrong pass phrase, or wrong file format?)
```

The url is working fine in web browser. Throwing error only from IDE.
Below are the screenshot for Git set up in IDE .
[image]

How to get rid of this error? Is there any certificate i should add or any settings change?

I have tried `git config --global http.sslVerify false`
and not working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like the ssh mismatch is the error. check if you've added the ssh key properly to your repository. have you tried generating the ssh more than once? then you probably have overwritten the key in your system. if that's the case, add the new key to your repository.

Comment: No. I didn't generate ssh key twice.

Comment: It is now working with SSH. I have generated an SSH key and performing clone using it. The error is throwing when I use HTTPS for cloning project.

Comment: maybe i sound silly, but have to tried to clone to the same folder using https:// where you've already cloned with ssh. i know i sound silly, but try to clone using https: to a new folder. follow how to init git and clone to a folder.  please provide some screenshots of the error not your setup.

Answer (score 0):

`git config --global http.sslVerify false` only disables certificate trust checks, it does not eliminate the need for a certificate.

The error basically means OpenSSL engine (used by git) cannot fine certificate file. The reason for this is likely misconfiguration of OpenSSL (e.g. wrong OPENSSL_CONF variable set, git config specifying the incorrect location of certificates, etc).

> Throwing error only from IDE

Do you mean it works on the command-line?

Comment: It is now working with SSH. I have generated an SSH key and performing clone using it. The error is throwing when I use HTTPS for cloning project.